# Understanding the proof of $||\mathbf{x} || \leq \sqrt{k}\max\left\{ |x_1|,..,|x_k|\right\}$

Tags: real-analysis

I know that the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and the triangular inequality operate on a vector $\mathbf{x}$ as a whole. But sometimes one need to go back and forward between a vector and its coordinates. So I found these two inequalities

(i)$$x_i \le ||\mathbf{x}||, \quad i=1,..,k$$

and

(ii) $$\|\mathbf{x}\| \leq \sqrt{k} \max \left\{\left|x_{1}\right|, \ldots,\left|x_{k}\right|\right\}$$

The proof for (ii)

$$ ||\mathbf{x}|| =x_1^2+...+x_k^2 \le k \max \left\{x_{1}^{2}, \ldots, x_{k}^{2}\right\} = ....$$

Q1: I do not understand the inequality $x_1^2+...+x_k^2 \le k \max \left\{x_{1}^{2}, \ldots, x_{k}^{2}\right\}$. I feel like it needs a proof for itself.

Q2: How are the inequalities used? Example of using these inequalites?

PS: I'm taking a course in real analysis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each number $x_j^{\,2}$ is smaller then or equal to $\max\{x_1^{\,2},x_2^{\,2},\ldots,x_k^{\,2}\}$ and since there are $k$ such numbers, their sum is smaller than or equal to $k\max\{x_1^{\,2},x_2^{\,2},\ldots,x_k^{\,2}\}$.

Comment: Thanks, that was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $x_i^2\leq max\{x_1^2,...,x_k^2\}, 1\leq i\leq k$, thus $\|x\|^2=x_1^2+...+x_k^2\leq k\cdot max\{x_1^2,...,x_k^2\}$

$$\|x\|=\sqrt{x_1^2+...+x_k^2}\leq \sqrt{k\cdot max\{x_1^2,...,x_k^2\}}$$

And $$\sqrt{max\{x_1^2,...,x_k^2\}}=max\{\sqrt{x_1^2},...,\sqrt{x_k^2}\}=max\{|x_1|,...,|x_k|\}$$ 
because $\sqrt{x}$ is an increasing function and $x_i^2\geq0$.

This inequality is used for example in proving that the euclidian norm and the maximum norm are equivalent.